# OnBecameInvisible() и OnBecameVisible() для другого объекта. [Unity3D]

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть префаб с такой иерархией (названия объектов без кавычек):

```
"Enemy Prefab" (Объект префаба (родитель); Этот объект сохраняется в ассеты в виде префаба)
 ∟"Enemy Sprite" (дочерний объект родителя)
   ⊢"Bullet Spawnpoint Up" (дочерний объект дочернего объекта родителя)
   ⊢"Bullet Spawnpoint Right" (дочерний объект дочернего объекта родителя)
   ⊢"Bullet Spawnpoint Down" (дочерний объект дочернего объекта родителя)
   ∟"Bullet Spawnpoint Left" (дочерний объект дочернего объекта родителя)
```

На "Enemy Prefab" весит скрипт "Enemy".
В скрипте есть такой кусок кода:

```
private void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Проблема в том, что `OnBecameInvisible()` срабатывает только если на объекте весит компонент "Sprite Renderer", но, как вы сами понимаете, на объекте префаба ("Enemy Prefab") нет компонента "Sprite Renderer". Компонент "Sprite Renderer" есть только на дочернем объекте родителя ("Enemy Sprite")

**Переходим к самому вопросу:**

*Как сделать так, чтобы `OnBecameInvisible()` считывал компонент "Sprite Renderer" с дочернего объекта? Что-то типа этого (код, конечно, нерабочий):*

```
private void OnBecameInvisible(gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>())
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

**Дополнение:**

*Вешать отдельный скрипт чисто для* `OnBecameInvisible()` *на дочерний объект родителя ("Enemy Sprite") не хочется. Хочется найти более элегантное и красивое решение, вместо создания ещё одного скрипта. Но если сделать так, как я хочу, невозможно, то придётся добавлять ещё один скрипт...*

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл вот такое решение:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html

Как пример кода:

```
public GameObject enemy;
bool isVisible;
void Update()
{
    isVisible = enemy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().isVisible;
}
```